# Angular 6 - Cannot Process data from web api

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting to process some data from an api in Angular 6. However, even though I can see in Network tab that the data below is being returned, I cannot process the data after this call completes.

My data returned by service:

```
    {"profile": "German DJ and producer based in Berlin. He is the founder of a label."}
```

My fetch:

```
  public fetchData(): Observable<DiscogsRecord> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
    map(response => response["profile"]),
    catchError(this.errorHandler("Error loading music data.", []))
  );
 }
```

My interface:

```
export interface DiscogsRecord {
  profile: string;
}
```

My ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.recs = [];
this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(records => (this.recs = records));
console.log(this.recs);

... etc
```

When I log this.recs, I get no data, just an empty array: []. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this `map(response:DiscogsRecord => response.profile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in where you have your logging.

```
this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(records => (this.recs = records));
console.log(this.recs);
```

Http requests are asynchronous, so when you call fetchData, it returns an observable and then executes your log statement. At that point it has *NOT* yet retrieved the data. When the data is retrieved, it calls the code within your subscribe.

So you need to move your logging INSIDE your subscribe.

```
this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(records => 
     {
        this.recs = records;
        console.log(this.recs);
      });
```

Comment: Well, *of course* they're asynchronous. :(  It's been working all along. Thanks!

Comment: is not it the same answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Just return the response in your service,

```
 return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
    map(response => response)
```

and you need to access within the subscribe

```
this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe((records) => { 
 this.recs = records;
 console.log(this.recs[0].profile);
});
```